# J/Link HMAC Base64

Tags: java, character-encoding, cryptography, hashing

I am trying to recreate a Java algorithm in Mathematica.  It is taking a key and signing a message using the HMAC and SHA256 algorithm.

The Java code for which I am basing it off is [here](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/)

I have dragged the apache commons 1.11 jar to (using a mac) /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Converters/Java/

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];

Mac = LoadJavaClass["javax.crypto.Mac"];
secretKeySpec = LoadJavaClass["javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec"];
base64 = LoadJavaClass["org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"];

key = "DDDD20942134FBB95AAF88198F260E06";
message = 
  "gethttps://api.gtcprojects.com/trade/orders1507882361.6882524";

keyJava = JavaNew["java.lang.String", key]
messageJava = JavaNew["java.lang.String", message]
```

Which gives

```
« JavaObject[java.lang.String]»
« JavaObject[java.lang.String]»

keyBytes = keyJava@getBytes[]
messageBytes = messageJava@getBytes[]
```

Which gives

```
{68, 68, 68, 68, 50, 48, 57, 52, 50, 49, 51, 52, 70, 66, 66, 57, 53, 65, 65, 70, 56, 56, 49, 57, 56, 70, 50, 54, 48, 69, 48, 54}

{103, 101, 116, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 97, 112, 105, 46, 103, 116, 99, 112, 114, 111, 106, 101, 99, 116, 115, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 116, 114, 97, 100, 101, 47, 111, 114, 100, 101, 114, 115, 49, 53, 48, 55, 56, 56, 50, 51, 54, 49, 46, 54, 56, 56, 50, 53, 50, 52}

signingKey = JavaNew[secretKeySpec, keyBytes, "HmacSHA256"]
```

Which gives

```
« JavaObject[javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec]»

mac = Mac`getInstance["HmacSHA256"]
```

Which gives

```
« JavaObject[javax.crypto.Mac]»

mac@init[signingKey]
test = mac@doFinal[messageBytes]
```

Which gives

```
{47, 105, 21, 95, -108, -119, 124, -33, -39, -98, 79, -98, 4, 87, 44, 88, 67, -53, 96, -1, 120, 91, 89, 114, -72, 23, -11, -115, 109, -24, -25, -39}
```

It appears everything is going well until I need to base64 encode it.

```
base64`encodeBase64String[test]
```

Which gives:

```
base64`encodeBase64String[{47, 105, 21, 95, -108, -119, 124, -33, -39, -98, 79, -98, 4, 87, 44, 88, 67, -53, 96, -1, 120, 91, 89, 114, -72, 23, -11, -115, 109, -24, -25, -39}]
```

It is also a little scary that there is negative bytes (CharacterCodes in Mathematica) in the results of the HMAC.

The correct answer is (confirmed by python)

```
L2kVX5SJfN/Znk+eBFcsWEPLYP94W1lyuBf1jW3o59k=
```

Comment: Does it work if you use ``Base64`encodeBase64String[...]`` (starting with a capital B)?

Comment: Could also use Mathematica's ``Developer`EncodeBase64[test]``

Comment: @WReach that did it!  ilian that also worked!  Maybe I am just new to JLink and wondering why when I assigned base64 to the class it didn't call that class but needed to use the Java class name Base64.  Interesting.  Thank you for the help.  If you put either of these in as an answer, I will accept.  If not, I will answer so people see that there was a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `` Base64`encodeBase64String `` -- with a capital "B".

The expression:

```
base64 = LoadJavaClass["org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64"];
```

returns a `JavaClass` object which is being stored into the variable `base64`.  As a side-effect, it also creates symbols which can access the static methods on the class.  By default, those symbols are placed into a context that has the same name as the Java class.  In this case, `` Base64`encodeBase64String `` is one of those static methods.  The `JavaClass` object stored into the variable `base64` has various uses, but static methods are not normally invoked through it.

As [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) notes in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159128/j-link-hmac-base64#comment423715_159128), *Mathematica* has built-in Base64 functionality.  `` Developer`EncodeBase64 `` is applicable in the present case.

Answer (score 3):

The recently [released](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/03/08/roaring-into-2018-with-another-big-release-launching-version-11-3-of-the-wolfram-language-mathematica/) version 11.3.0 introduced [`BaseEncode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseEncode.html) which would be useful here.

A complete example (including the HMAC computation) in Mathematica:

```
hmacBase64[method_, message_, key_] := 
 Module[{dkey, opad, ipad, blocksize}, 
  blocksize = If[method === "SHA384" || method === "SHA512", 128, 64];
  dkey = StringToByteArray[key];
  If[Length[dkey] > blocksize, dkey = Hash[dkey, method, "ByteArray"]];
  dkey = Normal[dkey];
  If[Length[dkey] < blocksize, dkey = PadRight[dkey, blocksize, 0]];
  {opad, ipad} = ByteArray[BitXor[dkey, ConstantArray[#, blocksize]]] & /@ {92, 54};
  BaseEncode[Hash[Join[opad, Hash[Join[ipad, StringToByteArray[message]], method, 
      "ByteArray"]], method, "ByteArray"]]
]

hmacBase64["SHA256","gethttps://api.gtcprojects.com/trade/orders1507882361.6882524", \
"DDDD20942134FBB95AAF88198F260E06"]

(* "L2kVX5SJfN/Znk+eBFcsWEPLYP94W1lyuBf1jW3o59k=" *)
```