# Keyed Hash for HMAC SHA256

Tags: cryptography, hashing

I'm trying to use AWS REST API's (because I can't rely on AWSLink`). The sample C# code from Amazon uses this a lot:

```
var keyedHash = KeyedHashAlgorithm("HMACSHA256")
keyedHash.Key = someByteArray
keyedHash.ComputHash(data)
```

But I can't figure out how to translate this to the Wolfram Language. Or maybe I can use SecuredAuthenticationKey directly with AWS? If so I'm not sure what the token endpoints are.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the expected outputs are for each step, including `someByteArray`? (Please use example data, not actual keys or something ) At first glance it looks like you might want `Hash`, but it doesn't include that specific algorithm.

Comment: Seems related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94891/hmac-implementation-in-pure-mathematica Check the answer of this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159128/j-link-hmac-base64

Comment: Thanks Carl, I saw your first link before posting but thought it was missing the point. Looking closer I think I need to try to reproduce what they're doing. I'll get back to you.

Comment: You also may want to look at [`GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair.html). IIRC in version 12 there will be some updates to this system.

Comment: I did see GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair in the prerelease but wasn't sure that was the right path. In any case, the answer is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167638/27694

I think the first link you suggested (94891...) is outdated. While Mathematica is incredibly backwards compatible something wasn't translating correctly to 11.3 or 12... or something is missing in their post

Comment: That's great! Shall we close this question as a duplicate then, if your question is fully answered by that other question?

Comment: We can close this @CarlLange and mark it as duplicate. I needed something that didn't use J/Link because it needed to work in the Wolfram Cloud which doesn't have access to J/Link or NETLink, correct?

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith I don't know, but that sounds right. I'm glad the implementation in the other question worked for you!